# Filter images in React with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a React app and multiple pages that are being imported to another `component` page.
So some of my pages would look like this

```
export default class Product1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <div className="product-box filterDiv shoes">
          <h2>Shoes 1</h2>
          <img className="product-image" src={product1} alt="" />
          <h5>$23.99</h5>
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The other pages are the same, just renamed `Product2, Product3...` and categories are added/changed in the `className`.
These pages are being imported into a main page `product.js` like so

```
export default class Shop extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div id="myBtnContainer">
             <button className="bttn active" onClick="filterSelection('all')">
            Show All
          </button>
          <button className="bttn" onClick="filterSelection('shoes')">
            Shoes
          </button>
          <button className="bttn" onClick="filterSelection('shirts')">
            Shirts
          </button>
          <button className="bttn" onClick="filterSelection('socks')">
            Socks
          </button>
          <button className="bttn" onClick="filterSelection('hats')">
            Hats
          </button>
        </div>

        <div className ="container">
            <Product1 />
            <Product2 />
            <Product3 />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then below the `product.js` is the JavaScript for the filter buttons

```
filterSelection("all");
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c === "all") c = "";
  // add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements
  // and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// show filtered elements
function AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) === -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// hide elements that are not selected
function RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// add active class to the current control button and highlight it
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("bttn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

However, I am getting the following error in my console
[image]

How do I fix this error?

Comment: You need to use refs to access dom elements like that!

Comment: Why you query the DOM when you using VDOM with React?

Comment: Typo? `<div id="mBtnContainer">` --> `.getElemntById('myBtnContainer')` (note: missing `y`)

Comment: @0stone0 no, in my app its typed correctly. I have a typo on here. (I'll fix it here).

Answer (score 0):

**You are thinking it in a Non-React way.**
Try to create a state, that holds every filter that is active, so you just change your function addClass and removeClass, to something like addSelectedFilter(filterValue) and removeSelectedFilter(filterValue)

and then, in your return, you should check, if the filter is in the array, e apply your classes based on these conditions, something like:

```
className={selectedFilters.includes("socks")? "bttn active" : "bttn"}
```

also you should store this selectedFilters as a state, is it clear for you? If you want some help to handle with this add and remove functions, let me know.